# python 2.7 : remove handler object or logger

Tags: python-2.7, logging

I want to remove this logger.

> backup.py

```
try:
        Logger = Log('PythonWork.backup') 
        Logger.info("backup task started")
        Logger.disabled=True
except Exception as e:
        errlogger = Error('PythonWork.backup')
        errlogger.error("Error: Error found back up service,failed.")
        Logger.error("backup task started")
```

> I tried `Logger.removeHandler()` and
>   `Logger.propagate`
>
> my log function

```
def Log(LOG_NAME):
    logger = logging.getLogger(LOG_NAME)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    filename=python.log
    fh = logging.FileHandler(filename)
    fh.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    logger.addHandler(fh)

    return logger
```

> my Error function

```
 def Error(LOG_NAME):
    logger = logging.getLogger(LOG_NAME)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    fileNameError=python.log
    fhError = logging.FileHandler(fileNameError)
    fhError.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
    logger.addHandler(fhError)

    return logger
```

In the backup.py file I dont want to excecute Logger object but it is executed. when I run this program and I want to stop or disable or remove that object.

Comment: sorry there is one mistake in error function line 6 fhError.setLevel(logging.INFO). It is fhError.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

Answer (score 9):

From your code, it seems the `Log()` function is creating a new log handler
at each call - see the last lines:

```
fh = logging.FileHandler(filename)
fh.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.addHandler(fh)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

So, you may have a myriad of `FileHandler` objects, removing one won't remove the others. I suspect this is your problem.

If you want to remove **all** handlers associated to a logger, you can do the following:

```
for handler in logger.handlers[:]:
    logger.removeHandler(handler)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's a bad solution in Python, because you're mutating the list logger.handlers while iterating over it. Best it iterate over a copy of the list (e.g., `logger.handlers[:]`). It will probably work to just simply set logger.handlers to the empty list `[]`, but the logging package acquires locks on each handler before releasing, so that is not as safe.

Comment: @johnthacker I edited the answer according to your comment

Answer (score 1):

Can't it just be:

```
logger.handlers = []
```

Answer (score 0):

This as the way to clear the logging handlers. It will probably call flush to make sure all messages have been sent.

```
logger.handlers.clear()
```